# GRETL - missing command to create dummy variables in GRETL

Tags: gretl

GRETL - How do I create a dummy variable with a column that contains the salary of an individual, being 1 when the salary exists and 0 when salary is empty using the missing command in GRETL

Comment: An example of what the data is like is the following table:

Induviduo - Salary
      1-800
      2--500
      3
      4--905
      5--5050
      6--850
      7-
      8--410
      9--1100
      10--7400

Comment: Did the code I wrote solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ok" function:

```
##### Creating Salary series #####
nulldata 10

series Salary = NA
matrix m = {800, 500, NA, 905, 5050, 850, NA, 410, 1100, 7400}

loop i = 1..10 
    Salary[i] = m[i]
endloop
##################################

series dummy = ok(Salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter way of doing what you need, and it will be much faster when working with large data as no looping is involved:

```
nulldata 3
series salary = {800, 500, NA}
series salary_dummy = NA

# if salary is _not_missing_ return '1', else '0'
series salary_dummy = (ok(salary)) ? 1 : 0
print salary salary_dummy -o
```

This returns:

```
        salary     salary_dummy
1          800            1
2          500            1
3                         0
```